# How to deal with memory efficiency of lots of small objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, memory

I have an application which takes data from a file and stores it for later use. Each line in the file corresponds to one object `Foo`, which contains `n` pairs of `Bar` objects which are made of a single character `String`, each with a distinct `Name`. So I store this data like so:

`Foo extends HashMap<Name, Pair<Bar, Bar>>`

where `Pair<A, B>` is my own class which just stores 2 values and provides some methods (`equals`, `hashcode` etc).

The problem I have encountered is that when I store `n=114` (this just happens to be the number in my test data) `Pair` objects in my `Foo` it should have a retained size of not much more than 228 bytes, when in fact it is more like 25kbytes. This means when I have ~1000 `Foo` objects I need 25MB of memory rather than 228kB, which is not really acceptable. (Note: the keys for each `Foo` object are the same, `fooOne.keySet().equals(fooTwo.keySet())`)

I am using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net) to profile my application, and when I delve into an instance of `Foo` I see:

```
Field           Type             Retained
-               
this            Foo              24750
...             
v table         HashMap$Entry[]  24662
  v [0]         HashMap$Entry    200
    v value     Pair             156
      v first   Bar              60
        ...
        > code  String           36
      v second  Bar              60
        ...
        > code  String           36
    v key       Name             72
      ...
      > name    String           36
  > [1]         HashMap$Entry    200
  > [2]        <HashMap$Entry>   -
  ...
  > [233]       HashMap$Entry    600
  ...
  > [255]      <HashMap$Entry>   -
```

So as you can see all the useful information is being surrounded by lots of useless (to me) data. If I had fewer, larger objects with the same data in I can see my useful:useless ratio would be better, but I can't see how I can implement this in any other way. Is there some other way I can store my data, but still be as convenient and easy to use as this?

**EDIT**

My application will need to be scalable to upwards of 6000 `Bar` instances and maybe as many `Foo` instances.

Comment: For this many objects I wouldn't worry about it. 25 MB is worth about 60 cents and is reusable.  How many objects do you imagine having?  There are lots of complicated strategies for reducing the amount of memory used. e.g. I have 4 billion rows with many columns I want to load into Java at once so I do quite a few tricks to get this to be efficient.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Upwards of 6000 `Bars` and a couple of thousand `Foos`

Comment: So you could be wasting $3.5 of memory (which might not be used for anything otherwise)  How much of your time is it worth spending to minimise this?

Comment: I've been asked to make it as memory efficient as possible, I am replacing an existing implementation of a system with one which is meant to be new and exciting and fast and wonderful, and at the moment it is just slow and hungry.

Comment: Compacting the memory is likely to be more memory efficient but **slower** I would start with a commrecial CPU/memory profiler and find where you spend the most CPU and the code create the most garbage in.  The data you retain is likely to be a small fraction of the time spent or the garbage you produce. Any other approach will be just guessing.

Comment: You maybe able to reduce the memory foot print by storing string data as ASCII char arrays. Unicode strings use 2 bytes per character, ASCII only 1. But as Peter said, you shouldn't worry about it right now and only look into optimisations once performance becomes measurably affected by the data set size. The java virtual machine is a very mature runtime environment, arguably one of the best and it is very good at managing memory.

Comment: A simple test program of 6000 Foo mapping to 12000 Bar is 733kb not 25MB. Using char instead of String in bar drops it to 663kb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I get your question right but in this situation using Flyweights may do the trick.

[Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Comment: but what is the data the objects can share ?

Comment: I think this would be the best solution, as each `Bar` is repeated many times but I am storing each one as a new instance. Thanks! This really should have occurred to me already...

Comment: There is a nice book named "Design Patterns". Knowing most of them means you will be able to correlate your design problems with already solved ones. You are welcome :)

Comment: My preliminary implementation has reduced my heap size from 25MB to 13MB!

Comment: It's great to hear that. Some more optimization and it will be under 1 :D

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of your problem is just object oriented code in general, and Unicode conversion specifically.

In Java a character in a string requires two bytes to store. So at the very least you can expect to double your memory usage versus keeping a file on the drive.

Each object, each little string is going to require a word worth of information because of the pointer the JVM needs to point to your object. So each pair of data is a word for the key and a word for the value plus the actual size of each. Now these pointers get added to the hash, which uses a word to point to itself, and several words to point to the entryset. And so it goes. This is object oriented programming.

Now you could change your code to store the pair as a simple char[2]. This would cut down on your memory foot print. Then when you want to interact with it, you could wrap the array with a Pair object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to drop the Bar and Pair objects and store a pair of as simple String object ,e.g. "ab" (where "a","b" currently correspond to a Pair made of Bar("a") and Bar("b"))

Probably use the Flyweight patterns to share the common names of all Foo objects, since you have `fooOne.keySet().equals(fooTwo.keySet())`

Comment: I already do share the `Name` objects! It's the `Bar` objects that I should be sharing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I have an application which takes data from a file and stores it for
>   later use

and later (in a comment)

> I've been asked to make it as memory efficient as possible

I suspect your most memory efficient solution is to store the file and parse it upon request, rather than parse and store in advance. But do you really want to do this and suffer the related performance costs ? I don't think your memory issues are particularly huge, but (as stated by others) I would investigate the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Comment: I should really have said "as memory efficient as possible within reasonable boundaries". Time efficiency is just as important too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/). You'll see that you need quite a lot more bytes than you think to store a class (string or other) in the JVM's heap.

36 bytes for a 1 character string sounds quite right, as you need to store a lot of metadata for the object that holds the character (be sure to account for UTF encoding) plus the string class overhead.